# Why is Get-PSDrive so slow?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the RemoteAdress for a Networkdrive. I'm doing it like this:

```
Get-PSDrive -name K -PSProvider FileSystem
```

I'm not joking, this command takes more than 120 seconds to complete in ISE and Terminal.

but if I run this inside `measure-command` it gives me the following output:

```
PS Z:\Powershell-Scripts\_DVLP> measure-command {get-psdrive -name K -PSProvider FileSystem}


Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 0
Milliseconds      : 5
Ticks             : 53547
TotalDays         : 6.19756944444444E-08
TotalHours        : 1.48741666666667E-06
TotalMinutes      : 8.9245E-05
TotalSeconds      : 0.0053547
TotalMilliseconds : 5.3547
```

why does this take such a long time when run outside of `measure-command`?

I'm on PSVersion 5.1.14393.0, Windows 10 Anniversary Update

however, I just need the `RemoteAdress` somehow so I could also use `net use K:`, but then I can't access the `RemoteAdress` Property.

How can I get my `RemoteAdress`?

Comment: my co-worker has the same PSVersion on Win 7 and it's the same story as on my computer, more than 120 seconds to complete. Is this a bug in our PSVersion?

Comment: `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_MappedLogicalDisk` throws a `COMException`

Comment: Have you tried [`Procmon`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) to see what's really going on?

Comment: Workaround: `((net use | Where-Object { $_ -match "K:" }) -split "\s+")[2]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was already identified and fixed in recent WMF 5.1 release. 
If upgrading is not an option you can found workaround in comments [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13703175-get-psdrive-abnormal-i-o).

Comment: there's no installer for Windows 10, or I can't find one. and I actually downloaded the WMF Version which is stated in the article for our win 7 machines and installed it a week ago, but they have the same problem. but still, this answer confirms it's a bug, so I accept it.

Comment: Would it not be beneficial to include some of those pertinent comments here?